# Actual add-on in UWP

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to create actual plug-in/extension/add-on for Universal Windows Platform app? By this, I mean creating something like a DLL package that can be downloaded separately by the users to enhance the functionality of an existing app so that users does not have to download a single big app, only the features that they need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP, plug-ins are called "App Extensions" - you can learn more about them in the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.AppExtensions` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appextensions.aspx)